# Extracting string from character array

Tags: c++, input, substring, character

I've tried memcpy / strncpy / std::copy but neither of them seem to work resulting the program to crash.

Here's what i need to do:

I'm trying to parse arguements from user input for instance.
"message -add 0xAE"

i need to fetch the 0xAE part into an integer, heres some pseudo-code
_input will hold the full string "message -add 0xAE"

```
if(strstr(_input,"message -add 0x")){
    char* _temp;
    std::copy(strlen("message -add 0x"),strlen("message -add 0x")+(strlen(_input)-strlen("message -add  0x")),_temp);
    /* or */
    memcpy(_temp,_input+strlen("message -add 0x"),strlen(_input)-strlen("message -add 0x"));
    int _value = (int)_temp;
    CLog->out("\n\n %d",_value);
}
```

Edit: Thanks Alan!

```
if(strstr(_input,"message -add 0x")){
            char* _temp = new char[strlen(_input)-strlen("message -add 0x")];
            memcpy(_temp,_input+strlen("message -add 0x"),strlen(_input)-strlen("message -add 0x"));
            int _value = atoi(_temp);
            CLog->out("\n\n %d",_value);
}
```

Comment: I can't see the part of code where you attempt to convert a string to an integer

Comment: _temp isn't initialised.

Comment: Whilst you don't want to use any 3rd party code and therefore are ruling out all good options parsers, your attempts to do this yourself are liable to end with many many defects. Why would you wish to reinvent this particular wheel? Parsing options is surprisingly hard. Unless you are a highly skilled developer you should be happy to use 3rd party code that works.

Comment: Thats exactly why I don't want to use ANY 3rd party code, because I'm not a skilled developer. How I'm supposed to learn how STL works if I don't (at least) try reinventing the wheel myself.Using boost::magic_function_that_solves_all_your_problems might indeed save time, but in the we end we have learned nothing.It's like waving the wand and   whispering the magic words, while knowing the outcome, without studying the magic itself.

Comment: Parsing options is hard. If you want to use it as a learning experience I think that's great. But if you are producing real code to be used by others a standard options parser wins. That's my main point.

Comment: @David Hefferman Sorry if I sounded a bit offensive, i didn't mean any offense. I'd like to thank you for your time. Others might say you're wasting it, but passing knowledge is far better than mindlessly watching football all night.At least in my honest opinion.You have answered all of my questions so far so I'd like you to know how much I appreciate it! Keep up the good work!

Comment: No offense taken at all. I'm just not sure what level you are at and what your goals are. Keep it up yourself!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
int value = 0;
char c;
for(int i = strlen("message -add 0x"); c = *(_input + i); i++) {
    value <<= 4;
    if(c > '0' && c <= '9') {
        // A digit
        value += c - '0';
    } else if(c >= 'A' && c < 'G') {
        // Hexadecimal
        value += 10 + c - 'A';
    }
}
```

?

Comment: It doesn't work properly. If i enter message -add 0x1 .. it returns 203 or something.

Comment: @minitech looks like you forgot to initialise value to 0

Comment: Won't work; value isn't initialized.  You're also treating the input as decimal when it's hex.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I'm too used to VB.NET right now, sorry. And I was thinking the alphabet came right after the numbers. I do read questions properly, even if I don't think straight all the time :)

Comment: @minitech: My condolences on the vb.net thing ;-)

Comment: @CareyGregory: I take offence at that. And I'm not kidding.

Comment: @minitech: Then I apologize.  I meant it solely in jest.

Comment: @CareyGregory: It's okay :) Everybody hates VB.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use C++, then steer clear of the various C functions and all of that nasty memory management.  I would recommend reading [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/).  It really is a top-notch book for learning C++ and actually using C++.  Here's another solution to your problem without the C string parsing routines:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


int
main()
{
    std::string const TARGET("message -add 0x");
    char const _input[] = "message -add 0xAE23";

    std::string input(_input);
    std::string::size_type offset = input.find(TARGET);
    if (offset != std::string::npos) {
        std::istringstream iss(input);
        iss.seekg(offset + TARGET.length());
        unsigned long value;
        iss >> std::hex >> value;
        std::cout << "VALUE<" << value << ">" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```